# How to build a timed chaincode?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, ethereum, hyperledger-chaincode

I want to write a timed chaincode. I wish the chaincode won't response to any invoke after a certain period. In Ethereum, I can do this by counting blocks. For example, I can make a smart contract valid only before block 100000. But in hyperledger fabric, I don't know how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem. Even though the block information is available via system chaincode I was not able to implement the querying of it from my chaincode elegantly. For my purpose, however, the following implementation was enough:

1. Introduce a `counter` state and initialize it with '0'.
2. Check this state in all your important chaincode functions. If it is lower than the certain limit, increase it by 1 and proceed with the function logic. Otherwise, throw error/print message/do nothing.
3. Based on the expected frequency of your transactions you can set more or less appropriate limit.

Maybe this soltion will work for you as well.

Comment: Yeah. It could be an option. But the frequency of transactions is unstable. For example, if I set a number 100 and when the counter reaches 100, then do something. But my chaincode could be invoked 99 times very quickly and never be invoked for the last time. So it's not a stable way to count the time.

Comment: Yeah. But similar thing happens with blocks. There are several events, that trigger the new block. The time from the last transaction not yet in block (by default I believe 2 seconds), the total size of transactions (99 MB by default). But as soon as your transaction lands in the block and there are no further transaction, no new blocks will be produced. That's why also the private data with given blockToLive can actually live forever if no one performs new transactions.

Comment: That's why I wish to find a relatively stable way to count time on Hyperledger Fabric. Such a need for a timer is very usual for some applications like auction applications. Maybe using a third party such as an outside time server is a solution. But it also brings a centralized risk.

Comment: Just interested. Could you summarize whether you were able to achieve timed chaincode and how?